# how to get version variable in aws cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, label, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have dynamodb arn string and want to combine manually about the string of stream arn.

```
arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789012:table/books_table
arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789012:table/books_table/stream/2015-05-11T21:21:33.291
```

Any one who knows how to get label in aws cloudformation of '2015-05-11T21:21:33.291' and give me example combine the dynamodb arn string to dynamodb stream arn string.

ps:

I can not use:

```
Fn::GetAtt: [ 'dynamodbTableLogicalId', 'StreamArn' ]
```

Because my dynamodb arn is the output string of my nested stack. I do not want export everything in nested stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the DynamoDB table in the template you can use `Fn::GetAtt` to get the stream arn.

```
Fn::GetAtt: [ 'dynamodbTableLogicalId', 'StreamArn' ]
```

If you are getting the stream date/label another way you can join it to the table arn with `Fn::Join`

Comment: Hi, I can not use Fn::GetAtt: [ 'dynamodbTableLogicalId', 'StreamArn' ]. That because my dynamodbTable is inside one of my nested stack. and the dynamodb arn is the output of that stack. I do not want output everything inside the stack.

Comment: Why not add the streamArn to the nested stack's outputs? Or output the stream arn instead of the table arn. (You could use Fn::Split, Fn::Select, and Fn::Join get the table arn from the stream arn, but you could just return both.